# Custom shortcode not rendering

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Have used a code sample from internet to make a shortcode to return a certain page. However the shortcode does not seem to be rendering but shows the shortcode text as it. The function has been defined inside `functions.php`.

The code is as follows:

```
/* Code taken from: 
 * http://alex.leonard.ie/2010/09/09/wordpress-shortcode-to-insert-content-of-another-page/
 */

function pa_insertPage($atts, $content = null) {
     // Default output if no pageid given
     $output = NULL;
     // extract atts and assign to array
     extract(shortcode_atts(array(
     "page" => '' // default value could be placed here
     ), $atts));
     // if a page id is specified, then run query
     if (!empty($page)) {
     $pageContent = new WP_query();
     $pageContent->query(array('page_id' => $page));
     while ($pageContent->have_posts()) : $pageContent->the_post();
     // assign the content to $output
     $output = get_the_content();
     endwhile;
     }
     return $output;
}
add_shortcode('insert_page', 'pa_insertPage');
```

Comment: errors? output? where is $content referenced?

Comment: the shortcode was reference like so inside a post [insert_page page="154"]

Comment: Please put how you call the short code within a post.  Also, from your link, do you test it using the `do_shortcode` method?

Comment: where is this filter applied..

Comment: @Jon the shortcode is used from the Wordpress text editor (edit post)

am not very versed in wordpress :)

Comment: Have you tried using the [Post Content Shortcodes](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-content-shortcodes/) plugin? (would make this easier for you since you don't know wordpress much, and get's rid of needing to do internal programming) ^^

Comment: @Jon will try and let know if it yields the desired results .. thank you .

Comment: @AbdulAli sounds good - hopefully it fixes your problem for you.  No need to reinvent the wheel, as [they say](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels.html). ^^

Comment: Your code works for me. Your problem is elsewhere, something else is interfering with the normal shortcut functionality, see [troubleshooting](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for the help.. the shortcode seems to be rendering now (the issue was likely the wrong function.php file :) ) ..

It seems that the Theme had another functions.php file which was to be used.. (not sure if the theme made a duplicate copy or was mistakenly done by a developer .. :) ) ..

regards

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the Question <sup>(which problem lies elsewhere, not in the code)</sup>, but an optimized version of the code. Publishing in Community Wiki mode, so no unintended reputation from down or up votes will count.

```
add_shortcode( 'insert_page', 'insert_page_so_15877376' );

function insert_page_so_15877376( $atts, $content = null ) 
{
    // Default output if no pageid given
    $output = '';

    // Access $atts directly, no need of extracting
    if( !isset( $atts['page'] ) )
        return $output;

    // Grab the page directly, no need of WP_Query
    // get_post() could be used as well
    $get_page = get_page( $atts['page'] );
    if( !$get_page )
        return $output;

    // Do Shortcode in case the other page contains another shortcode
     $output = do_shortcode( $get_page->post_content );
     return $output;
}
```